# How to import customized component from node_modules

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I forked a project on github and i edit some parts for my own. So im installing this customized project from github via ‘npm install’ there seems no problem. But when i try to import this package from node_modules  in this way

```
import InputTag from ‘vue-import-tag’
```

It cannot find the component but like this

```
import InputTag from ‘../../node_modules/vue-input-tag/src’
```

Do i need to register this folder to somewhere or how node knows where to look when we try to import package in first way?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link. Never load something from `node_modules` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you typo'd this line `import InputTag from ‘vue-import-tag’`? Should it be:

```js
import InputTag from ‘vue-input-tag’
```

Alternatively make sure that the module `vue-input-tag` is building correctly. Make sure it is creating a file called `inputTag.common.js` in `dist`.